# ¿Cómo listar las opciones para operaciones matemáticas básicas?

Tags: javascript, html

Compañeros tengo un código de un formulario en HTML el cual resuelve operaciones matemáticas básicas, al ingresar los valores de los números, se muestran los resultados para cada operación,lo que quiero es tener una lista desplegable para que se escoja la operación matemática que se desee y luego muestre el resultado, el código funcional es el siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Operaciones Matematicas</title>
</head>

<body>
<title>Operaciones Basicas</title> 
<script> 

function varios(){ 
<!-- Suma --> 
n1 = parseInt(Operaciones.txt_num.value); 
n2 = parseInt(Operaciones.txt_num2.value); 
Operaciones.txt_resultado.value=n1+n2; 
<!-- Resta --> 
n1 = parseInt(Operaciones.txt_num.value); 
n2 = parseInt(Operaciones.txt_num2.value); 
Operaciones.txt_resultado2.value=n1-n2; 
<!-- Multiplicacion --> 
n1 = parseInt(Operaciones.txt_num.value); 
n2 = parseInt(Operaciones.txt_num2.value); 
Operaciones.txt_resultado3.value=n1*n2; 
<!-- Division --> 
n1 = parseInt(Operaciones.txt_num.value); 
n2 = parseInt(Operaciones.txt_num2.value); 
Operaciones.txt_resultado4.value=n1/n2; 
} 
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<form name="Operaciones"> 
<center> 
<h1>Operaciones Basicas</h1> 
<p> 
Numero 1 
<input type="text" name="txt_num" size="20"> 
<p> 
Numero 2 
<input type="text" name="txt_num2" size="20"> 
<p> 
<hr> 
Resultado Suma
<input type="text" name="txt_resultado" size="20"> 
<p> 
Resultado Resta
<input type="text" name="txt_resultado2" size="20"> 
<p> 
Resultado Multiplicacion 
<input type="text" name="txt_resultado3" size="20"> 
<p> 
Resultado Division
<input type="text" name="txt_resultado4" size="20"> 
<p> 
<input type="button" value="CALCULAR" onclick="varios()"> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

El código del formulario que he realizado es el siguiente, pero no he podido enlazar las operaciones matemáticas:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="number">Numero 1:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="number2">Numero 2:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number2" id="number2">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="select">Operacion Matematica:</label>
      <suma>
        <select name="select" id="Select">
          <option value="2">Suma</option>
          <option value="2">Resta</option>
          <option value="2">Multiplicacion</option>
          <option value="2">Division</option>
        </select>
      </suma>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Calcular">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="number3">Resultado:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number3" id="number3">
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Aquí tienes, es algo corto para que lo entiendas mejor.**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  document.getElementById('c').addEventListener('click',function(){
  var op = document.getElementById('op').value,
  n1 = document.getElementById('n1').value,
  n2 = document.getElementById('n2').value,
  operacion = (op == 1) ? Math.pow(n1,n2) : n1*n2;
  document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = operacion;
  }); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" id='n1' placeholder='Numero 1'>
<input type="number" id='n2' placeholder='Numero 2'> 
  <hr></hr>
<select id='op'>
  <option value='1'>Potencia</option>
  <option value='2'>Multiplicación</option>
</select>
<input id="c" type="button" value="Calcular">
  <i>El resultado es: <i id='r'></i></i>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.